# How to replicate a website display glitch on the iphone in the desktop browser?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a responsive website and how it is displaying on the iphone. But I am not able to replicate the visual glitch by using Chrome or Safari and shrinking the window width or changing the user agent in the Chrome console to the iPhone I can only replicate the visual glitch when testing using an actual iPhone.

This makes diagnosing the problem hard as I cannot access the web developer console to inspect the element to see what is going on.

Are there any other options?

Comment: "I cannot access the web developer console" — Why not? https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/

Comment: Have you tried online iPhone emulators such as http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator (amongst many, many others)? Maybe one of those also has debugging facilities, although you won't find one with as many options as the web developer console has. If you can at least replicate the error using an emulator you can screenshot the result for advice :)